# Xdebug 3 update - cookie 'XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM' no longer works via php 7.3 cli

Tags: php, xdebug

I just updated xdebug from  v2.9 to v3.0.

To debug API calls I used to send along with the request a cookie set to **XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM**, but since the update this cookie does not seem to work anymore via the php cli.

I'm using PhpStorm 2020.2.

What's the alternative in Xdebug 3 ?

Comment: Also had problems with XDEBUG 3. first of al check that XDEBUG 3 is installed as an extension. this is what helped me (I'm not using cookies though). also notice that the listening port have been changed.

Comment: @naspy971 I seems you answered your question, please mark as closed!

Comment: @AdamP. there is no option to close because I answered my own question

Comment: @naspy971 You can't see this option: https://imgur.com/a/URO7jqH ?

Comment: I do see this option, what I'm saying is that the list of options inside the popup does not suit my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed my issue : The upgrade of Xdebug from 2.9 to 3.0 removed my environement variable XDEBUG_SESSION, so according to the documentation I had to **export XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM** again, now it works as before.